# Annotate text in facetgrid of sns relplot in python

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, annotations, seaborn, facet-grid

Using the following data frame (utilities):

```
    Security_Name          Rating    Duracion   Spread
0   COLBUN 3.95 10/11/27    BBB     6.135749    132
1   ENELGX 4 1/4 04/15/24   BBB+    3.197206    124
2   PROMIG 3 3/4 10/16/29   BBB-    7.628048    243
3   IENOVA 4 3/4 01/15/51   BBB     15.911632   364
4   KALLPA 4 7/8 05/24/26   BBB-    4.792474    241
5   TGPERU 4 1/4 04/30/28   BBB+    4.935607    130
```

**dataframe**

I am trying to create a sns relplot which should annotate the scatter plot points in respective facetgrid. However the out put i get looks something like this(without the annotations)

**relplot**

I can't see any annotation in any plot

**I have tried the following code:**

```
sns.relplot(x="Duracion", y="Spread", col="Rating", data=utilities)
```

I really don't know where to start to bring the annotations for this replot using facetrgid. The annotation should be the values of the column Security_Name

please advise the modifications. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using `FacetGrid` and a custom annotation function, you can get the desired result. Note that there is a good chance the annotation will overlap given the example dataframe provided:

```py
def annotate_points(x,y,t, **kwargs):
    ax = plt.gca()
    data = kwargs.pop('data')
    for i,row in data.iterrows():
        ax.annotate(row[t], xy=(row[x],row[y]))
        
g = sns.FacetGrid(col="Rating", data=df)
g.map(sns.scatterplot, "Duracion", "Spread")
g.map_dataframe(annotate_points, "Duracion", "Spread", 'Security_Name')
```

[image]